# Contact fetch (name, mobile number, email address and birthday) taking too much time

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch contact with name, mobile number, email address and birthday, but operation is taking too much time (by the way device has 2000 approx. contacts). Even UI is hanged, if I show a animation on my custom progress dialog, it is not animating.

(either fast contact fetching or animation should work at least).

(Even, I have used asynctask for both contact fetching and animation but I got same result).

**Here is my code**

```
ContactListClass.phoneList.clear();

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

            int progress = 0;
            // customIndeterminantDialog.setMax(cur.getCount());

            int i = 0;

            while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                ContactObject contactObject = new ContactObject();

                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

//                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                // Query phone here. Covered next

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                String phoneNo = "";
                String emailId = "";
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                    // Do something with phones
                    phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    phoneNo = phoneNo.replaceAll("\\W+", "");
                }

//                Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
//
//                if (emailCur != null || emailCur.getCount() > 0) {
//
//                    while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
//                        String emailContact = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
//                        if (emailContact != null) {
//                            emailId = emailContact;
//
//                        } else {
//                            emailId = "";
//                        }
//                    }
//                    emailCur.close();
//                }

                contactObject.setName(name);

                contactObject.setphone(phoneNo);
                contactObject.setEmail(emailId);

                contactObjectsList.add(contactObject);

                //customIndeterminantDialog.setProgress(++progress);

                pCur.close();
//                }
                i++;
            }

            customIndeterminantDialog.dismiss();

        } else {
            customIndeterminantDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: Use Asynctask to fetch contacts. Doing long operations on UI thread is not recommeded.

Comment: Even, I have used asynctask for both contact fetching and animation but it is not working

Comment: We cannot tell what's causing your problem if you did not post the *relevant* code.

Comment: @Enzokie Code link added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue using [AsyncTaskLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/AsyncTaskLoader)